# In what ports can we run a service on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, port, thrift

My situation: 
I'm trying to create an android app using unity that has a server running, so I can call the service from a PC. 
However, when I try to connect to the server I get the error message:

```
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy)
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP)
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remote_end_point)
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress[] ipAddresses, Int32 port)
```

Doing ping on the IP Address is fine, so the host is reachable, as far as I know android devices don't have firewalls, so my guess it is a problem with the port.

Currently I'm trying to run the service on port 9096, which works if I just run the application in the editor. Is this a valid port for android?
If not, what would be a valid one?

Do you have any other ideas on what the problem could be?

Thank you.

Additional info:
The device is Google Tango and I want to use Thrift to create a server and access the location of the device from a windows coomputer.

========================================================

## UPDATE: included code for server and client

```
public void startServerService()
{
    try
    {
        TangoService.Processor processor = new TangoService.Processor(this);
        serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9096);
        server = new TThreadPoolServer(processor, serverTransport);
        Debug.Log("Starting the server...");
        server.Serve();
    }
    catch (UnityException e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e);
    }
}


void startClient()
{
    try{

        TTransport transport = new TSocket(ipAddress, 9096);
        transport.Open ();
        TProtocol protocol = new  TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        client=new TangoService.Client(protocol);
    }
    catch(UnityException e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e);
    }


}
```

Comment: Is it possible that Android apps can't accept TCP connections, period?

Comment: post your `Service` code

Comment: @pskink that is I think the important part of the code.

Comment: @JanDvorak I hadn't thought about, but I would think it should. If you or anyone knows the answer to that please confirm. I will also look into it. Thanks

Comment: so what is your code?

Comment: @pskink It's basically those two functions startClient() and startServerService() should I also include the function when the data is requested?

Comment: @JanDvorak Android does accept TCP connections.

Comment: Technically any port above 1024 should be OK to use. How is your phone connected to the network? Are you trying to access it through Internet?

Comment: @m0skit0 The tablet is connected through wifi, and yeah i try to access it through the internet.

Comment: Then you most likely have firewalls/routers in-between that block your traffic and that you need to configure to allow incoming connections to the phone (e.g. NAT). Note that if the phone is connected through 3G then you cannot connect to it through Internet because most network operators do not allow incoming connections through 3G (at least all operators I know do not allow that).

Comment: @m0skit0 I think that's a possibility, however, wouldn't the firewall /router block the traffic also between two computers? Because if I run the same service in a different computer, but still in the same network, I do get a response

Comment: The traffic could be allowed for that computer but not for the phone. Check how NAT works. You can also traceroute to your phone to see if where the traffic is dropped.